# MS Access: Taking information from Login form table and passing to another form

Tags: ms-access, global-variables, vba

Hi I have a login form which requires the user to enter username and then password. The username and password is checked through in a table and then allows-does not allow the user access to fill in another form.

In the table there is information regarding the persons name, email, etc. In my second form I want the personal information already displayed so that they wont have to fill it in. Basically, by logging into the form and opening another form it will recognise who the person is and will automatically fill in their details. Thanks

Ken

Comment: What happens next? Why not write the log-in information to a table (bind the log-in form)?

Comment: The log-in information is in a table with all the other personal details. I want the second form to extract the data from the table and have it filled in as soon as it comes up. I am a beginner sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices. You can open the second form with OpenArgs that refernce the ID or name of the person on the log-in.

The syntax is ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx ):

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm(FormName, View, FilterName, WhereCondition, DataMode, WindowMode, OpenArgs)
```

So:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm",,,,,,Me.ID
```

The second form can then use the OpenArg to find or DlookUp ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb148913(v=office.12).aspx ) the record in the table, for example, you could set a textbox to:

```
 =DlookUp("Email","MyTable","ID=" & Me.OpenArgs)
```

You can open the second form bound to the users table and use the Where argument:

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm",,,"ID=" & Me.ID
```

This would be best, but it does depend on a bound table or query.

Finally, you can hide the log-in form and refer to the controls in a textbox:

```
 =Forms!MyLogIn!txtEmail
```

Comment: Thanks @Remou, I managed to pass over the ID over using <pre><code>DoCmd.OpenForm "ModSelect", , , "StudentID = 'me.username.value'"<pre/><code/> In the second form, I used default value as: =DLookUp("Surname","StudentID") I Should be adding in a criteria as this just generates the data for the first person in the table. How would I get it to generate the row of data corresponding to the StudentID? These are both primary keys and linked. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is wrong: DoCmd.OpenForm "ModSelect", , , "StudentID = 'me.username.value'" Do not put me.username.value in quotes. If you open the form correctly and it is bound, you do not need DlookUp. The above answer includes three options, you only need one of them :)

Comment: Could I send it to you to have a quick look? I tried changing the "Do.Cmd.OpenForm"ModSelect",,,Me.Username" it then asks me to fill in a parameter. The login page username appears as Unbound, so I think I have some problems binding it with the ModSelect Form. Thanks!!